# how to get a.out file?

Tags: c, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I have created a program in the ide and want to get a.out file. But after executing the command, I didn't find anything in the project folder.What's wrong?

[image]

UPD

[image]
upd

[image]

**UPD4:** i found this file , but now i can't execute it...

[image]

Comment: `-o finally_laba` is instructing the compiler to produce output named `finally_laba` and not the default `a.out`.

Comment: Also remove the `-V`

Comment: What's in the `x86` directory?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried it(. look at the third screenshot.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please post the output of `ls; qcc finally_laba.c`.

Comment: How about a `cd /home/student/ide4-workspace/laba_3/finally_laba` followed by  `qcc finally_laba.c`?

Comment: Or just get a decent IDE... the current one doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: @IanAbbott look at UPD4, pls. do I have to specify the full path?

Comment: No, you do not need the full path, a relative path will do.

Comment: @IanAbbott  okay so..then why doesn't it work? I want to run the written program through the command line, not through the ide.

Comment: (Losing the will to live a bit), try (1) `cd /home/student/ide4-workspace/laba_3/finally_laba`, (2) `qcc finally_laba.c -o finally_laba.out`, (3) `./finally_laba.out`.

Answer (score 1):

If `-o` is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in `a.out`.

Looks like your IDE set `-o` to filename, so `finally_laba` "is" your `a.out`.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't see finally_laba.out

Comment: it's `finally_laba` no `.out` was specified.

Comment: It should be literally just `finally_laba`. No reason for an `.out` anywhere.

Comment: Looks like the OP isn't compiling at all, but only printing the targets information.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I need exactly .out file. how do I get it?

Comment: If the name matters so much to you, change the IDE config to produce a different name or, if that doesn't work for some reason, simply rename the result.